# Remove emoji flags from text in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, emoji, python-unicode

I'm trying to remove all emojis, including emoji flag of Macau  from my Python string. I've tried several standard regular expressions and regex from the emoji lib, but do not succeed in removing it.
My code:

```
def remove_emoji(text):
    emoji_pattern = re.compile(
        u"(\ud83d[\ude00-\ude4f])|"  # emoticons
        u"(\ud83c[\udf00-\uffff])|"  # symbols & pictographs (1 of 2)
        u"(\ud83d[\u0000-\uddff])|"  # symbols & pictographs (2 of 2)
        u"(\ud83d[\ude80-\udeff])|"  # transport & map symbols
        u"(\ud83c[\udde0-\uddff])"  # flags (iOS)
        "+", flags=re.UNICODE)
    return emoji_pattern.sub('', text)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you perhaps porting this code from Python 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your patterns seem not to indicate the flag emoji (and possibly other glyphs) you are targeting.

E.g., to remove the flag:

```py
def remove_emoji(text):
    emoji_pattern = re.compile(
        u'(\U0001F1F2\U0001F1F4)|'       # Macau flag
        u'([\U0001F1E6-\U0001F1FF]{2})|' # flags
        u'([\U0001F600-\U0001F64F])'     # emoticons
        "+", flags=re.UNICODE)

    return emoji_pattern.sub('', text)
```

Note the capital-U (`\U`) escape signifying 32-bit hex values. Flags and emoji are *way* up in the high Unicode values. Also, flags seem especially complicated, as they're two-codepoint combinations. Once you've got the right characters targeted (as demonstrated with the Macau flag), you can extend with a character set (here demonstrated with an expression for all the pairs for the [Regional Indicator Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Indicator_Symbol).

You can also start to add back in descriptions for other emoji and symbols; here for example done for basic emoticon block.

With the above definition:

```py
flag = '\U0001F1F2\U0001F1F4'
emote = '\U0001F620'
​
print("flag: {!r} gone: {!r}".format(flag, remove_emoji(flag)))
print("emote: {!r} gone: {!r}".format(emote, remove_emoji(emote)))
```

Yields:

```py
flag: '' gone: ''
emote: '' gone: ''
```

You can further extend this with the other blocks you'd like to target. I recommend you look them up individually, looking for the 32-bit notation. Note that you will often see them written `U+1Fxyz`; these need to be restated as `\U0001Fxyz` for Python. If you want to remove all the symbols ("all emoji") you can do so with a broad character set. But if you want to be precise and remove only a limited set of symbols, you will need to use care. One of the sets you're targeting, for example, [Transport and Map Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_and_Map_Symbols), comprises five independent ranges, with overlaps on the full emoji set.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to sound like a bit of self promoting but I have a Python library that can do that (among other things). The library is [cucco](https://github.com/davidmogar/cucco) and basically you would do something like:

```
from cucco import Cucco
cucco = Cucco()
cucco.replace_emojis('Your text')
```

Not sure if this will work perfectly for you but would be nice if you could give it a try and let me know the result. I'm always open to feedback so I can improve the library ;)